# Twitter Bootstrap - force responsive / layout width for specific device / useragent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any possibility to manually switch to / force display of selected layout width on specified device or screen size? I mean, I would like to have responsive as usual, but when screen is exactly 1366px wide (or maybe is specified useragent) it should show 768 (SM layout) instead of 1280 (LG)
(without manually adding a condition to many, many media queries...)
Maybe there is a way to tell the browser, that it's width is different than it measured.

Am I even thinking in good direction or it makes no sense?
Thank you

Comment: col-sm-* is from 768px to 991 and from 992 to 1199 is col-md-* and from 1200 and up is col-lg-* and all the percentages are the same for each col so if it adds to 12 you can manipulate them as you wish. But if you just use col-sm-* it will be the same from 768px and up, there's no need to add further column classes. The grid is fluid so the layout will adjust as necessary. Look at the grid examples on GetBootstrap.com

Comment: I know this. For me the site is working perfectly.
But the client said, it should display SM layout on exactly his device which has 1366px wide screen.
And this is not good news when you got already completed running website. So I'm looking for a method to tell the browser (javascript?) that the viewport has different dimensions to emulate this. Or something similiar. This is my idea but I don't know is this even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own customized Twitter Bootstrap

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

In **Media queries breakpoints** section, there are the variables you need.

Comment: I know this, but the point is, that I have completed and running website - so even if I change breakpoints and replace my bootstrap, I would have to modify media queries in many places in website's styles.
I need some method to "switch layout", like "emulate screen size" or something...

Comment: And I'm already using all breakpoints sizes for 4 layouts, so cannot just use one free, define it's size and paste in all occurances.

Comment: I think you need to modify all your styles at least one time (with js you can only modify window size, append or remove styles), but you can use a *dynamic css* via php and passing a *width* param, like this: `style.php?width=1400` if you want to go this way, tell me to post sample code